# ssh -X foo@host then su bar then run X app with local display, while bar also logged in?

Tags: ssh, xorg, remote

I want to `ssh` into another machine, using one user account, then `su` to another user and run X programs as that user, with the display on my computer.

The case when the 2nd user is not logged in to X is nicely covered by [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89650/how-to-ssh-y-and-then-su-another-user-and-still-forward-x-applications-to-y), but what when the other user *is* logged in?

That [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89659/23542) suggests you copy the `.Xauthority` file, created by `ssh -X`, in the first user's home dir, to the `su`-ed to user.

However, when they are logged in, they already have an `.Xauthority` file and presumably they won't like me overwriting that...

So is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can place the copy of the `.Xauthority` file wherever you want and then:

```
export XAUTHORITY=/path/to/.Xauthority
```

Then any programs launched which try to connect to X will use that Xauthority file.